# How do I read and store string of arbitrary length using malloc and realloc in C?

Tags: c

I have a structure

```
typedef struct store
{
   char name[11];
    int age;
} store;
```

and a main function(below is part of it):

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int inputs;
    char line[100];
    char name[11];
    char command[11];
    store read[3000];

    while(i < 3000 && gets(line) != NULL)  
    {
        int tempage;
        inputs = sscanf(line, "%10s %10s %d", command, name, &tempage);
        if (inputs == 3)
        {
            if (strcmp(command, "register") == 0)
             {
             strncpy(read[i].name, name,10);
             read[i].age = tempage;
             i++;
             ....
```

I need to modify it so that it can read a line of arbitrary length, and store the name from the line which is also a string of arbitrary length using malloc and realloc.

How should I approach this?

Comment: First, **never use `gets()`**. Never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is read the line in smaller increments, and resize your buffer as you go.

As an example (not tested and not meaning to be particularly elegant, just an example):

```
char *readline(FILE *f)
{
   char *buf = NULL;
   size_t bufsz = 0, len = 0;
   int keep_going = 1;

   while (keep_going)
   {
      int c = fgetc(f);
      if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
      {
         c = 0;             // we'll add zero terminator
         keep_going = 0;    // and terminate the loop afterwards
      }

      if (bufsz == len)
      {
         // time to resize the buffer.
         //
         void *newbuf = NULL;
         if (!buf)
         {
            bufsz = 512; // some arbitrary starting size.
            newbuf = malloc(bufsz);
         }
         else
         {
            bufsz *= 2; // issue - ideally you'd check for overflow here.
            newbuf = realloc(buf, bufsz);
         }

         if (!newbuf)
         {
            // Allocation failure.  Free old buffer (if any) and bail.
            //
            free(buf);
            buf = NULL;
            break;
         }

         buf = newbuf;
      }

      buf[len++] = c;
   }

   return buf;
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what the code does.  I would have to replace gets/fgets and sscanf with a similar code, right?

Comment: @Draygon Replace your `fgets` with `line = readline(stdin)` and make sure to 1. check `line` for `NULL` so you don't crash when it fails and 2. after every call to `readline` call `free` on the buffer when you are done with it.  You can continue using `sscanf` on the returned string.

Comment: Although ... if you're planning on using `sscanf` with `%s` you will need to make sure the argument has an allocation big enough to hold the result.  A simple way to do this would be to make the argument's allocation size be `strlen(line) + 1`.  (Overall I would say `sscanf` doesn't have a great interface...)

Comment: wait, how would the %s on sscanf work since name could be an arbitrary length as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name[11] to *name;
Allocate memory for that everytime using [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).

By the way, `register` is a keyword in C language. You can't use it like you did !

Comment: oh, I used store instead of register on my current code, but I thought if would be more clear if I used register.

Comment: i'm not sure how to store a line with unlimited length

Comment: I don't want to give code ;-) learn about malloc from that link and then you can easily do it yourself. Or search google to see how memory is allocated dynamically for structures.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
char* name;

name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Comment: First, if you're using C (not C++) you *never* cast `void*` away explicitly.  Second, I don't think he wants to allocate only 1 char ....

Answer (score 0):

This alternative approach is similar to @asveikau's, but economize on the use of malloc() by copying on the stack.

Please do not use this for homework answer.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char * slurponeline(FILE *f, int s) {
 const int size = 4096;
 char buffer[size];
 char * r;
 int c,i=0;
 while( i<size && (c = fgetc(f),c>=0 && c!='\n')) buffer[i++]=c;
 if (0 == s && 0 == i) return 0;
 r = (size==i)? slurponeline(f,s+size):malloc(s+i);
 memcpy(r+s,buffer,i);
 return r;
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
 FILE * f = fopen(argc>1?argv[1]:"a.out","rb");
 char * a,*command,*commandend,*name,*nameend;
 int age;
 while (a = slurponeline(f,0)) {
  char * p = a;
  while (*p && *p == ' ') ++p; // skip blanks.
  command = p;
  while (*p && *p != ' ') ++p; // skip non-blanks.
  commandend = p;
  while (*p && *p == ' ') ++p; // skip blanks.
  name = p;
  while (*p && *p != ' ') ++p; // skip non-blanks.
  nameend = p;
  while (*p && *p == ' ') ++p; // skip blanks.
  age = atoi(p);
  *commandend=0;
  *nameend=0;
  printf("command: %s, name: %s, age: %d\n",command,name,age);
  free(a);
 }
}
```