# What is the Max string length one can input in a c programme?

Tags: c

If i use a[10][100] to input 10 strings with max length 100,it works fine
But there is a compiling error if i use a[10][100000]

Comment: With your keyboard?

Comment: Any limit is most likely coming from your terminal shell (on top of any limits you enforce in your code)

Comment: Please show the lines of code where you **input** this string

Comment: @KerrekSB Regular physical keyboards have natural press-count limit, around 1e6 afaik. So, the limit is ~4.8e7 for AT or PS/2 keyboard. USB keyboards may be hot-swapped, thus no limit exists.

Comment: I would prefer file redirection or pipe. (check `<`, `|` for your shell and `freopen`)

Comment: @KerrekSB I literally laughed aloud reading your answer :D

Comment: If the error you're getting (why not tell us what it is?) is something like "array too large", you're going to want to use dynamically-allocated memory. See previous questions like these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346904/read-text-from-a-file-and-realloc-when-needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982548/how-do-i-read-and-store-string-of-arbitrary-length-using-malloc-and-realloc-in-c

Comment: Try changing your big array from a local to a global array (that is, declare it _outside_ of `main` or any function.)

Comment: Try `static char a[10][100000];`

Comment: In one lifetime, My guesstimate is 2.759.400.000 chars.  You should dynamically-allocate it on a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

There's no limit imposed by the C language itself that I know of.

You would want to be careful about the memory allocation of the array or other data structure you read it into.  Simply declaring

```
char inbuf[100000];
```

probably wouldn't be the best idea, especially if it was a local (stack) variable.  (Some systems get upset if you have really gargantuan variables declared on the stack.)  In this situation, I would usually use `malloc` and `realloc`, to grow the buffer as big as I needed it.

Most operating systems impose a limit (usually a pretty small one, as these things go) on the maximum length of a line you can type on the keyboard, but that limit applies only to lines your program reads from the keyboard, not that it reads from files.

Both in principle and in practice, there's nothing stopping you from writing a program to read a line of pretty much unlimited length from a file (or a pipe, or a TCP stream, or just about any other input source other than the keyboard), and I can tell you that I've done so plenty of times.

Answer (score 0):

It can be as long as your input variable size you define.

Comment: If the _string_ comes from the keyboard, it walks through quite some buffers, each of which may have other restrictions. (Driver, shell, etc)

Answer (score 0):

OP's unposted error message is likely telling that too large of a local variable is being made.  To make large variables, suggest using `malloc()`.

Per the C language, the maximum array size is no larger than `SIZE_MAX`.  Other factors may considerable further limit a system's maximum `char[]`.  These are usually large values  This typically means there is no practical limit on user input from the code's point-of-view.  Yet robust code would limit, and detect, user input of insanely large input as more likely errant input or a hacker attack than legitimate.

```
#define N 4096
char *buf = malloc(N);
if (buf && fgets(buf, N, stdin)) {
  size_t length = strlen(buf);
  if (length >= N-1) Handle_LongInput();
}
```

The proper value for `N` is program dependent.