# C supporting dynamic arrays

Tags: c, arrays

As far as I know C doesn't support dynamic arrays. Here I implemented a dynamic array **tasks** with a variable length **TASK_NO** which I am fetching through scanf. The code is compiled without error and it is running properly. What can be the reason? Please clarify.

```
scanf("%d" , &TASK_NO);
int counter=TASK_NO;
struct task_info tasks[TASK_NO];
printf("total: %d\n", sizeof(tasks)/sizeof(tasks[0]));
```

`

Comment: This is called a VLA (variable length array), and is supported since C99 (although not required in C11)

Comment: The `sizeof()` keyword is evaluated at compile time, not runtime, so will not give the correct number for `total`

Comment: What is the reason for down vote? Is the question quality so poor or the answer is so well known ?

Comment: Not my down-vote but I expect it's because of any/all of the following: (a) no prior research effort shown, (b) answer is readily available via a simple Google search, (c) numerous duplicates on StackOverflow already.

Comment: @ user3629249, since C99 there are runtime requiremens for sizeof.

Answer (score 4):

`struct task_info tasks[TASK_NO];` is not a dynamic array. It is a variable length array whose length will be decided on run time.

---

Dynamic arrays would be arrays whose size can be changed as and when required. Think of an array which you initialized to contain `10` elements and later would want to change it to contain `20` elements. That is not present in `C`.

---

You can however implement dynamic arrays yourself using pointers, dynamic memory allocation and `realloc()`. But that won't be something that is a feature provided by the language.

Comment: Well, it can if you implement it yourself using dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Yes, that can be done in C, but not as a syntactic feature. It can be done by declaring a pointer, allocating space to that pointer and treating the pointer as an array. You change the array size with `realloc`.

Comment: @szczurcio True. I think Stroustrup started that around 1979. It kinda got out of hand though.

Comment: There is no reason to say that is not possible, just because we don't know if there is a way or not. We do have pointers and malloc. Should be enough.

Comment: @Michi, I changed the answer a little. Do take a look.

Comment: @Haris I saw that now :). But like I said, we have [pointers and malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655093/array-with-undefined-length-in-c/33656480#33656480)

Comment: @Michi, Ya.. I added your suggestion also. :)

Comment: @Haris ....and you got my vote for that :d.