# How to create live dynamic memory allocation in an array of numbers, while taking input?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

So My mission is to keep accepting numbers from users until the user input a negative number.
My algorithm should be:
1)start in the size of 2.
2)double the size every time it reaches the end, free the older one.
3) stop when user hits negative number.

**I know I haven't used free and didn't check if the allocation is successful, I'm trying to keep the code as clean as possible for you guys.
Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *reallocate(int* numbers,int i,int arr[]);
int main() {
    int numbers[2];
    int *nums = numbers;
    int i = 0;
    int size = 2;
    while (i<size)
    {
        scanf("%d", (nums+i));
        if (*(nums + i) <0)
            break;
        i++;
        if (i == size) {
        nums=reallocate(nums,i,numbers);
        size = size * 2;
        }
    }
    puts("Stop");
    return 0;
}
int *reallocate(int* numbers,int i, int arr[]) {
    int newsize = 0;
    newsize =i * 2 * sizeof(int);
    numbers = (int *)realloc(arr,newsize);
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: what is `live dynamic memory allocation`???

Comment: You can't call `realloc` on an array you allocated statically to begin with.

Comment: Mehh I had a feeling. Any solution offerd ? :)

Comment: Well, by saying live allocation, I mean that it's "on demand". As long as the user keeps entering numbers it keeps growing.

Comment: @IsanRivkin you should allocate memory for array dynamically, and then reallocate it on demand.

Comment: @stek29 Thank you you did it great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `malloc`'ed arrays only with `realloc`
Here is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *nums;
    size_t size = 2;
    nums = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    size_t i = 0;

    while (i < size && nums != NULL) {
        scanf("%d", (nums+i));
        if (nums[i] < 0)
            break;
        i++;
        if (i == size) {
            size *= 2;
            nums = realloc(nums, size * sizeof(int));
        }
    }

    if (nums == NULL) {
        puts("Error");
        return 1;
    } else {
        free(nums);
        puts("Stop");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works great thanks ! I got the wrong idea of making a static array and pointing at it, thanks! *Small correction, you forgot to add sizeof(int) in the realloc, just for the people who read here, but it works perfect!

Comment: Why are you casting `malloc`? By the way your code has memory leaks.

Comment: @Michi Can you please show me where? 
And about casting `malloc`, do you have any ideas how to do this in C, not C++ (I mean no `vector`)?

Comment: @stek29 I really don't understand your Question. Any way there is no need to cast `malloc` in C, because of its return type which is VOID*. If you ask that, then you probably don't know that. Maybe because you are used with `C++`? or maybe because you are using a wrong compiler

Comment: @stek29 Where `malloc` takes place, `free` should be present too. You should know that.

Comment: @Michi you mean `free` before `return`?

Comment: @Michi I'm not used to C++ at all. I've not understand you, but now I did, I google'd and I'm surprised. Now I'll not cast `void *`.

Comment: Try to understand [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/RU69HK3r) and then [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/VcuLgkk9)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99073/discussion-between-michi-and-stek29).

Comment: return type of sizeof is `long unsigned int` this means that `size` and `i` shouldn't be `int`

Comment: @stek29 Try to understand [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655093/array-with-undefined-length-in-c/33656480#33656480).

Comment: @Michi Aren't we in chat?

Comment: @Michi should't we check that `nums` isn't  `NULL` after `realloc`?

Comment: @stek29 Please get a book. I really don't have time for this.

Comment: @Michi Ok, I'll. Thanks anyway