# Structure not displaying entered values in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, console

I'm trying to print the entered values from struct. Program is able to get all input values but after show() method call it does jumps out of the program in exit without displaying my entered values.

I'm not getting any error or warning at all.

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Book{
    char *title;
    short price;
};

void show(struct Book b[],const short n){
    short i;
    printf("\nBOOK DETAILS");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\nRecord no %d / %d",i+1,n); //exits after displaying this line
        printf("\nTitle : %s \nPrice: %d",b[i].title, b[i].price);
    }
}

void get(struct Book b[],const short n){
    short i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\nRecord no %d / %d",i+1,n);
        printf("\nEnter book title & price: ");
        scanf("%s %d",&b[i].title, &b[i].price);
    } 
    show(b,n);
}

int main()
{
    struct Book b[3];
    get(b,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Call sequence is like main() --> get() -->show(). I'm using Dev cpp compiler with .c extension of my code file.

Answer (score 2):

`title` member of `struct Book` is just a pointer to `char *`, so when you define a `struct Book` structure, no memory has been allocated for its `title`.
Either define `title` as an array or allocate memory for it.

Comment: How do i allocate memory? I'm trying to get any size length from user so can't use array.

Comment: Then your requirements are more complex.  If there is no upper bound on how long the string can be, you can't even have a fixed buffer to read that string in the first place.  I recommend you consult your favorite book on C and read the chapters about strings and dynamic memory.  It's a non-trivial problem.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9982882/1553090) for a potential starting-point.